# Puppeteer - wait for element to have certain value

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How can I wait until an element has a certain value?

For example, some button on a page changes the value of an input field from "No Value" to "Value X". The problem is, I don't know how much time will it take so `page.waitFor()` is not an option.

I thought I could use `page.waitForSelector(input:contains('No Value'));` but that does not work as far as I understand.

Possibly `page.waitForFunction()` should work, but I am not sure what function to write there. Would I use a `page.evaluate` that returns the value of the input maybe?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforfunction) `page.waitForFunction` will wait until the function passed to it (as a closure or a string) returns a truthy value.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch({headless : false}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitForFunction('document.getElementById("wait").value != "No Value"');
  console.log('Value changed!');
  await browser.close();
});
```

Comment: How would this `waitForFunction` function call look like when using ElementHandles?

Comment: @Ini Sorry can't advise on that, honestly I always prefer the explicit nature of `page.evaluate` and never ever even touch handles.

Comment: No problem. I just think that using a string for code looks IMO pretty horrible (`'document.getElementById("wait").value != "No Value"'`)

Comment: I feel quite the opposite way :) to me it feels short and simple enough.

Comment: @Ini try this: `await page.waitForFunction(\`document.getElementById("wait").value != "No Value"\`);`